How does Tinder gives me only new profiles? [Database design]
I have probably swiped 10k profiles either left or right.
If I open the app tomorrow I will get 10 profiles I have never seen.
How can these profile be queried efficiently?
For sure an SQL query of the type “give me all profiles excluded x, y, z, ……” (where x,y,z is a huge list of profiles I have already seen) is not viable
Some ideas I collected online

“Each user profile might have metadata indicating the users who have already interacted with it. This can help quickly exclude profiles you have swiped on.” This seems crazy, imagine a girl in LA area, probably would have an array of 1 million uuids of users which interacted or not with her, seems unrealistic
some sort of inverted index, but i haven’t really understood how it could help in this scenario without creating multiple MBs of metadata per user (!!!)

I do understand that probably the solution to this problem is not optimal and either some heavy query is necessary or some significant metadata needs to be stored but still the solutions that came to my mind all seem too inefficient

That's a very interesting question. i have been looking online for some clarity but as you said there's only speculation as most of the dating apps around do not share their structural design online.
your first option does solve the issue, but as you said it becomes exponentially large each day (considering that each day x new accounts are made)
but the answer still lies there in my opinion.
And the key is in your question, imagine a girl from LA with whom about 100k profiles have interacted with her in the past month for example, if we do solve the issue this way (n°1) 100k new tables of "interactions" which most likely will only have the interactedID (girl's profile) the interactorID (the guy/girl swapping through profiles), and the Flag dictating the interaction.
this solution again does solve the issue only in teory, but does create a scaling issue considering the amount of users, the db would be a shitshow of data.
But we can put a limit to this interactions creating as little tables as possible.
insted of following this pattern:
--Create a new Profile:
--For each existing profile a new table  dedicated to the interaction with me is created
we can limit the amout of tables created:
1-Create a new Profile:
2-A new Group of profiles that has been queried based on your starting interests (location, sex, age etc) has been created and marked as GroupOfInterest
3-you now have a already queried array of possible matches linked to your account (this could litterally be saved locally)
4-you can start swipping through those profiles each time you are not interested in someone and swipe them (right/left i don't remember) you put the profile id in a new group of DenyList.
--anytime you want to look for new people you follow the  step n°2 clearing the existing GroupOfInterest and filling it with new interests but inside the GroupOfInterest there cannot be people with a profileId of those you have in your personal DenyList.
with this you only create a table linked to you of users you are not interested in.
and you cicle through that each time you create a new query and look for new people.
I may have got this wrong but it does seem a more viable solution to the one table bind to me for each people on the platform
